Actionbar in Android 15 is overlapping activity contents
I'm not defining any Toolbar in my XML files and I'm using the default ActionBar defined at theme:
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondary</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppBaseTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppBaseTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>        
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>  

  

No issues in Android 14 and previous, but in Android 15 the Activity contents is displayed at fullscreen and ActionBar is overlapping the Activity contents.
It's possible to prevent it then have the same behavior in Android 15 I have in previous versions?
Thanks

in res/values-v35/styles
    <item name="android:windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement">true</item>


Thanks for the answer. I have tried it but doesn't work. Finally it had work when I have added android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the root activity layout
